# Razor - How to store html special character in variable

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

On my html page, I want to make a list from a collection of entries in my model. However, some of those entries may be null, and in that case I want to have an empty list item, like so:

- Something
- Something else
- 
- More stuff

I do that by inserting a non-breaking space character. (regular whitespace won't generate empty list items) Here's a code snippet:

```
<ul>
    @{ 
        foreach (var x in Model.Entries)
        {
            var rayon = x.Rayon ?? "&nbsp;";
            <li>@rayon</li>
        } 
    }
</ul>
```

Sadly, this does not work because it instead pastes `&nbsp;` verbatim.
And removing the quotation marks, and/or adding @: at the start, won't compile.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Html.Raw`.

use like this

```
<li> @(Html.Raw(rayon)) </li>
```

Comment: That produces an empty string alright, but I do not need an empty string. I specifically need an invisible character in a string, e.g. the ``&nbsp;``, because otherwise the list item will not display.

Comment: You need to be careful with Html.Raw - you open up potential XSS vulnerabilities. i.e. what if the value is: "<script>alert('hello')</script>" ...

Comment: It is producing `&nbsp;` . you can check it in console.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I was still trying the other solution, accidentally. Thanks!

Comment: @AdaTheDev: I know, It is dangerous, but here in this case, it is safe. as it is not user entered value. so it is safe to use.

Comment: But how do you know? The model data could be pulled out from a database, where it was stored as-is from user input....

Comment: @AdaTheDev It did eventually come from user input, yes. I now modified the code so it only uses Html.Raw if x.Rayon = null, and otherwise just displays the regular value. Less concise, more safe.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"&nbsp;"` just give a blank string:

```
var rayon = x.Rayon ?? string.Empty;
```

In fact, I think you can even just scrap that variable assignment together and just use x.Rayon as-is - a null value should have the same effect

```
<ul>
    @{ 
        foreach (var x in Model.Entries)
        {     
            <li>x.Rayon</li>
        } 
    }
</ul>
```

**Update:**
Both above work for me. So, if still not working, it looks to be down to CSS/styles on your ul.

e.g.
OK, I think this is down to CSS/styles on the ul that you have then (both above work fine for me). e.g. the following CSS would hide empty li elements:

```
ul li:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

So, check out your CSS.

If you don't want to change the existing style, you could add an extra class to your CSS and apply that for just this instance.
i.e.
CSS:

```
ul.show-empty-li li:empty{
    display:list-item;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="show-empty-li">
...
</ul>
```

Comment: Sadly, as I expected, string.Empty will not produce an empty list item. A list item with nothing, or nothing but whitespace, will not display on an html page. That is the reason I need an invisible character that is not simply whitespace, such as a non-breaking space.

Comment: Update added :)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a CSS thing. However, I'd rather not modify it, as there is already a ton of CSS attached to this element and I don't think I quite understand it fully, so the other solution will work fine; but thank you for your help :)